# Optional parameter in retrofit method

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have 2 methods:

```
@POST("/example")
fun getSomething(@Body string: String)

@POST("/example")
fun getSomethingWithHeader(@Body string: String, @Header header: String)
```

Sometimes I have to post with header sometimes without, it works but in my opinion it could be one method especially with kotlin default args.

But something like:

```
@POST("/example")
fun getSomethingWithHeader(@Body string: String, @Header header: String = "")
```

will probably send also header but empty.

Is it possible to merge these 2 method into 1 ?

Comment: `@Header header: String` isn't valid syntax, you need to provide a name for the header like `@Header("YourHeader") header: String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the header as nullable like this:

```
@POST("/example")
fun getSomethingWithHeader(
    @Body string: String, 
    @Header("YourHeader") header: String? = null
)
```

From https://square.github.io/retrofit/:

> If the value is null, the header will be omitted. Otherwise, toString
> will be called on the value, and the result used.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Kotlin you can build like [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1144) example